# How to get element in jQueryUI draggable revert function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I know that jQuery draggable can accept a function for [`revert`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) action.

```
$(".clipboard-li").draggable({
     revert: function (event) {
         console.log(event) // boolean value
     }
});
```

But the parameter being passed to this function is a boolean.
How can I get the the element currently being dragged in this function?

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve? Because `revert` is an option, not event. So this is only to tell `draggable` whether the element should revert to its start position when dragging stops.

Comment: You might want to look at the [`stop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) **event** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`revert`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) is an option where you can set

> Whether the element should revert to its start position when dragging stops

If you want to get the element after you drag it somewhere use [`stop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) event

```js
$(".clipboard-li").draggable({
  revert: function(event) {
    return $(this).hasClass("revert"); //You can set it either to true or false
  },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log($(event.target).attr("class"));
  }
});
```

```css
.clipboard-li {
  cursor: move;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="clipboard-li">
  </div>
  <div class="clipboard-li revert">
  </div>
  <div class="clipboard-li">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `revert` handler function runs under the scope of the element being dragged; it's not passed in as an argument. As such you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element:

```js
$('.drag').draggable({
  revert: function() {
    return this.prop('id') != 'allow';
  }
})
```

```css
.drag {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="drag" id="allow">Allowed</div>
<div class="drag" id="deny">Denied</div>
```